# npm installation failure libp2p-websockets

Tags: github, npm-install, libp2p

I'm currently working on an IPFS project.
While installing the dependencies - When I run

> npm i libp2p-websockets

I get the following error message:

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/hugomrdias/pull-ws.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! ERROR: Repository not found.
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
```

I have already setup the SSH configuration.

Do you have any idea how this could be solved?

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting the same error in one of my projects after running `npm install`.

It is probably because **hugomrdias** has removed/made private the **pull-ws** repository.

So, far I am not sure what to do next. I will mail him with this issue.

Comment: I found the solution of the issue just now.
I updated the versions of packages listed in package.json file and that worked.

Comment: @zx238 What did you do, specifically? Can you post it as an answer?