# IPFS repository not found haadcode/ipfs-pubsub-room.git

Tags: dependencies, ethereum, ipfs, js-ipfs

I'm following the read me instructions at https://github.com/redacademy/vue-ethereum-ipfs
I got to the point of doing npm install and get:

/usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/haadcode/ipfs-pubsub-room.git
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
......

That repository does not seem to exist, and i found a repository by the same name https://github.com/ipfs-shipyard/ipfs-pubsub-room . I think replacing will fix this but i don't know how to do this.

This person seems to have the same issue, maybe there is a link [npm installation failure libp2p-websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66654646/npm-installation-failure-libp2p-websockets)

Answer (score 0):

That library is unmaintained, and hasn't had a commit in 2 years.

If you really want to use that library, likely the best way to start is by updating the local packages in `package.json`. I believe you can accomplish this by following the instructions [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/updating-packages-downloaded-from-the-registry) which are effectively just:

1. `cd /path/to/vue-ethereum-ipfs`
2. `npm update`

Just be aware that because the library is unmaintained, you may run into many confusing or unexpected issues as you move forward.